# How is lpCmdLine stored?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to understand how lpCmdLine behaves, and it seems to be somewhat counter intuitive.

Originally, I thought it was just a pointer to the whole command string, but this code shows this not to be the case, as displaying lpCmdLine directly shows garbage.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void alertf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[80];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    sprintf_s(buf, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    MessageBox((HWND)0, buf, "Message Box", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);  
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    alertf("lpCmdLine: '%s'.", lpCmdLine);

    return 0;
}
```

How is lpCmdLine stored internally?

**Solution**

My alertf should use `vsprintf_s` instead of `sprintf_s` because its' argument is a varargs.

This one change confirms that lpCmdLine is indeed as I originally thought, a c string of the whole command line.

Comment: Note it's only (and always) an ANSI form of the command line; you can use the `GetCommandLineW()` API function to get the Unicode command line.

Comment: @Dmitry, on StackOverflow, you do not need to add "ANSWERED" to your question title, nor do you need to provide the solution in your original question.

Comment: @dreamlax Sorry about that.

Comment: Accepting an answer below is the only action you need to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lpCmdLine` is indeed a simple pointer to the command string.

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  MessageBox(NULL, lpCmdLine, "DEBUG", MB_OK);

  return 0;
}
```

The issue seems to be with your `alertf` function, where your `sprintf_s` call isn't doing what you think it does. You actually need to use `vsprintf_s` here due to the presence of the `va_list`:

```
void alertf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  char buf[80];
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  vsprintf_s(buf, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  MessageBox((HWND)0, buf, "Message Box", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

The code works perfectly after that.

Comment: I was crossing my fingers my totally unique and innocent alertf wouldn't do anything wrong other than cause a buffer overflow... I guess now I know what vsprintf does. Thanks!